# CSS Checkbox Styling

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm working on styling a CSS checkbox. Things are looking pretty good but I have one issue. If the box label is a lot of text the boxes end up inconsistently aligned.

How would I change my code below to have the check box be on the LEFT side of the text so things are consistent?

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7295tvp0/

```css
span.bigcheck-target {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 20px!important;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck {
  position: relative;
  left: -999em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f096";
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck:checked + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f046";
}

span.bigcheck {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bigcheck-target {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">Short
    <input name="amenities" value="wifi" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
  </label>
</span>

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">Much longer name
    <input name="amenities" value="personal_video" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span  class="bigcheck-target"></span>
  </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```css
span.bigcheck-target {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 20px!important;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck {
  position: relative;
  left: -999em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f096";
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck:checked + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f046";
}

span.bigcheck {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bigcheck-target {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<span class="bigcheck">
<label class="bigcheck">
    <input name="amenities" value="wifi" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
    <span> Short</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="bigcheck">
    <label class="bigcheck">
    <input name="amenities" value="personal_video" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span  class="bigcheck-target"></span>
    <span>Much longer name</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten you code using flexbox.

You can achieve this without changing markup:

```css
span.bigcheck-target {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  /* space between icon and label */
  margin-right: 5px;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck {
  /* don't show standard checkbox */
  display: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f096";
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck:checked + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f046";
}

span.bigcheck {
  font-size: 20px;
  /* checkbox on every line */
  display: block;
}

label.bigcheck {
  /* become inline flex-container */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* center vertically every item */
  align-items: center;
  /* inverse layout in row */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">Short
    <input name="amenities" value="wifi" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
  </label>
</span>

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">Much longer name
    <input name="amenities" value="personal_video" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span  class="bigcheck-target"></span>
  </label>
</span>
```

Or with markup changes, where you place text after checkbox icon (recommended way):

```css
span.bigcheck-target {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  /* space between icon and label */
  margin-right: 5px;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck {
  /* don't show standard checkbox */
  display: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f096";
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck:checked + span.bigcheck-target:after {
  content: "\f046";
}

span.bigcheck {
  font-size: 20px;
}

label.bigcheck {
  /* become flex-container, putting checkbox on every line */
  display: flex;
  /* center vertically every item */
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">
    <input name="amenities" value="wifi" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
    Short
  </label>
</span>

<span class="bigcheck">
  <label class="bigcheck">
    <input name="amenities" value="personal_video" type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
    <span  class="bigcheck-target"></span>
    Much longer name
  </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try`span.bigcheck-target{float:left;}`

And remove : `span.bigcheck-target:margin-top: 20px!important;`

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML needs a bit of reworking. Use `div` elements to create the rows. Give your `input` elements `id` values and then use the `label` elements so that they don't have to wrap those `input` elements by using the `for` attribute.

Then, simply set a unified width for the labels:

```css
span.bigcheck-target {
    font-family: FontAwesome; 
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: 20px!important;
}
input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck {     
    font-size: 2em;
}

input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck + span.bigcheck-target:after {
    content: "\f096"; 
    
}
input[type='checkbox'].bigcheck:checked + span.bigcheck-target:after {
    content: "\f046"; 
    
}

label { 
    font-size: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="amenities1">Short</label>
  <input id="amenities1" name="amenities" value="wifi" type="checkbox" name="cheese" value="yes">
  <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="amenities2">Much longer name</label>
  <input id="amenities2" name="amenities" value="personal_video" type="checkbox" name="cheese" value="yes">
  <span  class="bigcheck-target"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your content after your "input" and "span"

And to stop your users from highlighting your content use:

```
.bigcheck { user-select: none; }
```